# linq using multiple .where statements

Tags: c#, linq

I've been using linq for some time but I don't think I understand it as well as I thought:

assume I have a list of Fruits

```
class Fruit {
 string name {get; set;}
}
//listOfFruits has a random number of fruit objects in it
listOfFruits;
```

if I want to get all fruit objects where the name equals `Apple` I do this:

```
var apples = listOfFruits.Where(x => x.name == "Apple").ToList();
```

my first question is, if I stack `.Where` statements, will both of them filter against the main list? or does the first `.Where` get a new result set, then the next `.Where` filters against the new result set?

are the following the same:

```
var applesAndOranges = listOfFruits
 .Where(x => x.name == "Apple")
 .Where(x => x.name == "Orange")
 .ToList();

var applesAndOranges = listOfFruits
 .Where(x => x.name == "Apple" && x.name == "Orange")
 .ToList();
```

if neither of these returns a list of both apples and oranges, how do I query against the main fruitList to get all fruits that have name `"Apple"` and `"Orange"`

Comment: use “or” || instead of "and" &&

Comment: @sstan I'm guessing there's one fruit called `Apple` and a *different* fruit called `Orange` and he wants both.

Comment: @sstan see Steve's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want the `OR` operator, which is two pipes: `||`. This returns all items in the last that either match the first expression, or the second.

```
var applesAndOranges = listOfFruits.Where(x => x.name == "Apple" || x.name == "Orange").ToList();
```

Comment: and what happens if I use 2 separate `.Where`s? does that do 2 levels of filtering

Comment: My guess is it would essentially do an `AND`. But the good thing about programming is it's easy to find out!

Comment: Doing a .Where(f => f.name == "Apple").Where(f => f.name == "Orange") defiantly acts like an AND and you would get zero results.